# Animating a view change in iPhone and Android

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

Im trying to make a "UINavigationController type animation" in a Titanium project, however currently when I do the animation it does sort of a "pop back" animation where the view "comes out" of where the other one "went to". I have managed to figure out what's the value that determines where the animation ends, that is, the `left` property of the animation, but how do I set where the animation starts?

code to control animation:

```
function hideOldWindow() {

    window.animate(animateOut, function(){});

}

function showNewWindow() {
    var old = views[currentView];
    window.remove(old);
    currentView = (currentView + 1) % views.length;
    var win = views[currentView];
    viewControllers[currentView].onBecomeVisible();
    window.add(win);
    window.animate(animateIn, function(){});    

}

var animateIn = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    animateIn.left = 0;
    animateIn.duration = 250;
    animateIn.curve = Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT;

var animateOut = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    animateOut.left = -screenWidth + 1;
    animateOut.duration = 250;
    animateOut.curve = Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is UINavigationController type animation, but to control where the animation starts, you have to set the left property of the view (this works for views I didn't try it on windows).

For example, to animate a view to appear, from left of the screen to the center, you can change the showNewWindow method to this:

```
function showNewWindow() {
    var old = views[currentView];
    window.remove(old);
    currentView = (currentView + 1) % views.length;
    var win = views[currentView];
    viewControllers[currentView].onBecomeVisible();
    window.add(win);

    // NEW LINE
    window.left = -screenWidth + 1;

    window.animate(animateIn, function(){});    

}
```

Now, window would appear from -screenWidth + 1 to left = 0.

Maybe you have to add a timeout before you animate the window to get it works.

Hope it helps